# Files saved to Cache dir are always MODE_PRIVATE?

Tags: android, file, caching

There are two options to save to internal storage:

1. files dir, which is a persistence folder which **doesn't** get deleted when storage space is low:

   outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
     outputStream.close();
2. cache dir, which is a persistence folder which **gets** deleted when the storage space is low:

   file = File.createTempFile(fileName, null, context.getCacheDir());

**My question:**
Will files saved to the cache dir act like the MODE_PRIVATE in the files dir?
meaning - will they be accessible only to my app, or will other apps also be able to access the files?

Comment: They will be private to your app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will files saved to the cache dir act like the MODE_PRIVATE in the files dir?

Yes.

> will they be accessible only to my app

Yes.

> or will other apps also be able to access the files?

No, unless you provide access by some other means, such as a streaming `ContentProvider`.

Comment: Once Again CommonsWare, you deliver.